# How to change color swatch of colored greyscale pictures using ExtendScript in InDesign?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I've got the following problem/situation:

- 12-page document (ID CC 2015)
- one frame with a greyscale picture per page
- the pictures are colored with the same color swatch (e.g. "universal") on all pages (white arrow, applied color swatch)

What I want to do now, is to write a script to color every picture with a different color swatch, e.g. the picture on page 1 with color swatch "1", the picture on page 2 with color swatch "2" etc. 
But I don't know how to access the picture itself (instead of the frame) and change its color. Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.
It currently sets random color for the images and only looks for rectangles. You could  use

```
page.allPageItems
```

instead. (if you also have images in ovals or polygons)

```
// the main function
var main = function() {
  var doc = app.activeDocument; // get the current document
  // loop the pages
  for (var i = 0; i < doc.pages.length; i++) { 
    var page = doc.pages[i]; // isolate the page
    // loop all rectangles
    for(var j = 0; j < page.rectangles.length;j++){
      var rect = page.rectangles[j]; // isolate a rectangle
      // test if there is an image inside
      if(rect.images.length > 0){
        var image = rect.images[0]; // isolate the image
        // asign a random color from th swatches
        image.fillColor = doc.swatches[Math.floor(Math.random()* doc.swatches.length -1)];
      } // end if image
    } // end loop j rectangles
  } // end loop i pages
} // end of main
main(); // run it
```

Comment: This works fine already, thanks!
But how could I asign a fixed swatch for every page? Like "a-1" for page 1, "a-2" for page 2 and so on?

Comment: I was able to solve it - thanks again :)  `var _col = "a-"+(i+1);  
_img.fillColor = _dok.swatches.itemByName(_col);`